# Order IQueryable by grandchild property dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, iqueryable

I have an issue with sorting a table. The table columns looks something like this:

| ID | Property1: Object | Property2: Object | Property3: int |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

The table has a sorting options that currently sorts something like this: `.OrderBy(e => EF.Property<object>(e,sortingColumn))` where `sortingColumn` is the name of the property/column that is being sorted on.

This is working fine for properties such as the ID or Property3 which is an int. But on my object properties it defaults to sorting on their ID. For those I want it to order by another subproperty such as `Code`. Meaning that is the `sortingColumn = Property2` I want it to order by `Property2.Code`.

Is there any good way to achieve this without making custom sorting methods for each column?

Comment: You can use LINQ to dynamically build the sorting expression based on the column to sort.

Comment: How? I ended up just having a condition for the specific column that orders it how I want and then the other columns are ordered as explained in the original post.